# Put json asnwer into html tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm learning ajax and I'm facing a huge problem, which I can't solve. I send a few variables into php, I do various checks there and I return string values to ajax. I can display those into `textare`a (strange that results instantly disappear ) and input field. All i want to do is display those into `div`s. Could anyone explain how can I do it, I will leave some commented code below. Thanks! P.S It's all about displaying registration form error's for user, maybe I could use a different method? Feel free to give some suggestions. Thanks again!

php.php

```
<?php


 //various checking here
echo json_encode(array(
'email_error' => $email_error,
'password_error' =>$password));
?>
```

html

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

</head>
<body>


<form>
Your email:
<input type = "text" id = "email"><br>
Your password:
<input type = "password" id = "password1"><br>
Repeat password:
<input type = "password" id = "password2"><br>
<button type = "submit" id = "push_button">PushMe</button>
</form>
<div id ="email_errors"> </div> <--I want to put variable $email_errors here -->
<div id = "password_errors"> </div> <--I want to put variable $password_errors here -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type =                           "text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

java_script.js

```
$(document).ready(function ()   {

$('#push_button').click(function() {

$.ajax({
url: "php.php",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json", 
data: {
email: $("#email").val(),
password1: $("#password1").val(),
password2: $("#password2").val() 
},
success: function(data) {

$("#email_errors").val(data.email_error); // i return these values (i tried html data type either
$("#password_errors").val(data.password_error);
}
});

}); 
})
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: `div` does not have a `value` attribute. You want to use `.html()` -> `$("#email_errors").html(data.email_error); $("#password_errors").html(data.password_error);`

Comment: Still nothing, i can see my strings only if i change divs into input fields.

Comment: before using **data.email_error** or even **data.password_error** try to convert the data string to json format by calling **data = window.JSON.parse(data) then you can use data.email_error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want the string variables to show inside the Divs? If that's all you want to do you have to use 'html' instead of 'val':

```
success: function(data) {

    $("#email_errors").html(data.email_error);
    $("#password_errors").html(data.password_error);
}
```

If your data comes back in the form of a JSON abject and you want to show the whole object you can do something like this:

```
success: function(data) {

    $("#email_errors").html(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

ALSO: (I don't know if it works the same in php), your `$('#push_button').click()` might be generating a postback, thus erasing the divs inner HTML. Try putting `return false` at the end of your click function to stop the postback from happening:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#push_button').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "php.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            email: $("#email").val(),
            password1: $("#password1").val(),
            password2: $("#password2").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {

            $("#email_errors").html(data.email_error); // i return these values (i tried html data type either
            $("#password_errors").html(data.password_error);
        }
    });

    return false; // this should stop the postback
});
```

})

Comment: How do i specify that $("#email_errors").html will contain 'email_error" from php file? By the way, my array holds only 1 element.

Comment: My experience is limited to .NET Aspx so I don't know how to assign `email_error` from the php back-end. I'm sure somebody else here can help you out with that.